# Git attributes (smudge, clean) distributed over repos

Tags: git

Is there any way to distribute smudge and clean hooks to remote repository? It's stored in `.git\config` so it is not tracked by Git.

Our client use slightly different environment and SVN(!) so we have to branches so we could merge our changes. It would be great if I could share those hooks for smudge and clean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer are [`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes). A slightly more objective description how to set the filters can be found in the [man-files](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html).

Put your attributes into a `.gitattributes`-file and save it into your project-folder. You're then able to track and commit it like other files.

Unfortunately, changing the filter itself needs you to access the `.git/config` of your client at least once. In my opinion you have two options for realizing that: deliver a second project-specific config or change the filter-calls to invoke delivered scripts.

#### Deliver the git-config

This is a simple approach to version an additional part of the git-config. We're going add a additional include-path to the repo-config and a additional config-file within the repository.

This is how i added another include to the `.git/config`:

```
[include]
  ../.gitconfig
```

Then you'd create the `.gitconfig`-file - i tested it with the `user.name`-setting:

```
[user]
  name = Mickey Mouse
```

After that you'll add the `.gitconfig`to your repo. Try your changes with:

```
$ git config user.name
Mickey Mouse
```

But i must admit that this constellation is a **security-risk** since you're able to overwrite all configuration-settings with a commit.

Another possible - and safer but more elaborate - solution would be to create the filters in the config and let them point to scripts within your repository.

Comment: Yes, I know about .gitattributes file. The question is if there is way to store hooks to smudge and clean(body of those functions) in repository, not only in .git\config.

Comment: Sorry - i misunderstood you. If you can access the clientside `.git/config` i'd try to include a tracked config-file. I can't test it now but i'll check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to add them directly to the repo along with instructions about how to copy them over to the .git directory.